# Drupal using FBOauth - How to get Facebook registered members to be not blocked automatically

Tags: facebook, drupal, content-management-system, drupal-7, fbconnect

On Drupal v 7.21, using FBOauth 7.x-1.6.

When members register on my client's site using Facebook connect through the FBOAuth module, their status is automatically set to "Blocked". Is there a good way to validate users connecting with Facebook so that they don't default to Blocked? Or does one have to manually change them to Active?

Comment: I just scanned through the code for that module, and it doesn't create accounts as "blocked" ? Line 161 of `includes/fboauth.fboauth.inc` uses `user_save` with a `status` of `1`, which is active.

Comment: The line actually says:
    `code`'status' => variable_get('user_register', 1) == 1 ? 1 : 0


I tested it, and my tested FB user went right to Blocked. Does that mean my user_register variable is not right?

Comment: Very strange, I done a clean `git clone` and I don't see what you see. Regardless, yes. You'll need to find where that option is and change it.

Comment: I'm just going to change it to set it to 1. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In admin/config/people/accounts set "Who can register accounts?" to Visitors.

In drupal new users need admin approval by default.